# Comparing GWT vs Echo2

Tags: gwt, echo, echo2

I am currently proposed to do my web portal using GWT however I have researched that its closest competitors is Echo2. But what are the differences between them?

Comment: Many differences and some similarities... Want more specifics? Provide more specifics :P Otherwise this question will get closed for being "subjective and argumentative"... which I think it should either way - test both frameworks on a small test project and choose the one you feel better about.

Answer (score 1):

I finde the article "[Comparing the GWT to Echo2](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=40804)". Hope it will be useful for you.

But by my opinion GWT will be better choice then Echo2. GWT more popular so you has more chances to get suppot by GWT community.